# Use of inline accessor functions from different files

Tags: c, embedded

I am trying to use accessor functions to avoid having a global outside the module where it belongs. To avoid function call overhead, I would like to use inline modifier.

The example is:

adc.h

```
inline void ADC_request_calibration( void )
{
    ADC_calibration_trigger = 1;
}
...
```

adc.c

```
#include "adc.h"
int ADC_calibration_trigger = 0;
...
```

consumer.c

```
#include "adc.h"

void function( void )
{
    ADC_request_calibration = 1;
}
```

In this way it obviously will not work as adc.h cannot see ADC_calibration_trigger. 
Adding the variable declaration to adc.h directly or with extern does not seem a good idea since we would stop hiding the variable (the purpose of the accessor function).

How can accessor functions be used with the inline modifier?

Comment: You cannot both have inlining and physical separation of translation units. Inlining means, by definition, that the consuming TU sees the definition.

Comment: So I have to choose between hiding the variable, or function overhead?

Comment: @rpica Yes, you'll have to choose. Also, your current definitiion on `ADC_request_calibration` in adc.h creates an externally linkable function in addition to the inline code, which would mean you could only include adc.h from one place. To avoid creating an externally linkable function, define it as `static inline`.

Comment: If you go the inline route, you cannot hide the variable, but you could use the common convention of prefixing symbols with one or more underscores if you don't want user code to use them.

Comment: @rpica: Yes, you would need *some* kind of indirection to achieve proper hiding. If the user can see the definition of how to get at the variable, then she can use that definition directly, too. But, as others have said, don't try to enforce stuff like that. Just tell people what they can and cannot use. The goal of API design isn't to prevent malicious attacks.

Comment: In my experience, most compilers treat inline as only a suggestion anyway, so you may not be getting the optimization you want even going this route.

Comment: A modern toolchain might support link-time optimisation (LTO), which re-compiles the code across translation units. If you are really up for speed, I'd check this. AFAIK none of the overpriced commercial toolchains support this, but the "cheapo" gcc/binutils does.